# How to get a customized number of decimal places in tex.sprint / directlua / qrCode?

Tags: strings, lua, qrcode, directlua, numprint

The number of decimal places is "9" in the following example: string.format("\%0.9f", X).
How can one achieve the replacement of the fixed "9" decimal places with   "NumberOfDecimalPlaces" (in LuaLatex) ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nolinks,forget]{qrcode}%
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\PrintNumber}[1]{
\qrcode[version=5]{
    \directlua{
        X = #1
        if X < 0.01 
        then NumberOfDecimalPlaces = 3 
        else  NumberOfDecimalPlaces = 2 
        end
      tex.sprint (string.format("\%0.9f", X))
}}}% 

\PrintNumber{1}
%
% Doesn't work: ("\%0.NumberOfDecimalPlaces f", X)
% Doesn't work: ("\%0.NumberOfDecimalPlaces{f}", X)
% Doesn't work: ("\%0.NumberOfDecimalPlaces(f)", X)
% Doesn't work: ("\%0.{NumberOfDecimalPlaces}{f}", X)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is to build the proper string in lua to pass to `string.format`. You want to change `"\%0.9f"` to `"\%0." .. NumberOfDecimalPlaces .. "f"` as `..` concatenates strings in lua.

Changing your example gives the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nolinks,forget]{qrcode}%
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\PrintNumber}[1]{
\qrcode[version=5]{
    \directlua{
        X = #1
        if X < 0.01
        then NumberOfDecimalPlaces = 3
        else  NumberOfDecimalPlaces = 2
        end
      tex.sprint (string.format("\%0." .. NumberOfDecimalPlaces .. "f", X))
}}}%

\PrintNumber{1}

\end{document}
```